# HTTP to HTTPS for single page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to apply rewrite rule which redirect payment page http to https. I want https only for payment page and if user click on home tab it should go to http not on https

example:

http://example.com/index.php

http://example.com/about.php

https://example.com/payment.php

http://example.com/home.php

Comment: Look at the documentation of `RewriteCond`

Answer (score 2):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/payment\.php$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/payment\.php$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks Arne but my problem is my page is successfully redirecting to https page after that all my site is running in https mode. I want https only for payment page and if user click on home tab it should go to http not on https

Comment: Try the edited version. I can't test it here but it should work.

Comment: @Arne +1 good answer. However, i've added some details in your code to make it work as expected